# MySQL - 2 databases with same tables

Tags: mysql, replication

i have 2 databases, HRD and Sale. HRD was replicated from other database server, and i have done the replication.

The problem is how can **customer** and **employee** in **SALE** database automatically have same data as **customer** and **employee** in **HRD** database?

so when the replication master update,insert or delete customer or employee tables in HRD, customer and employee in SALE automatically  updated too.

HRD has 3 tables

```
Customer
Employee
Suplier
```

Sale has 4 tables

```
Customer
Employee
TransactionM
TransactionD
```